# "Super W" neoprene pads for electronic drum decoupling platform?

Tags: home-studio, acoustics, isolation, studio-design

I am looking to build a platform for my electronic drums to decouple vibrations (mostly from the kick) to the building structure. The ['tennis ball' platform](http://dezmedia.com/tennis-ball-drum-riser/) is a recommended DIY solution often found online, but I'd rather look at purchasing pads or mounts for ease of installation (not to mention that they are a little easier on the eyes).

I have found the following product at local dealers:

**Super W pads**.  Here is the product page: https://mason-ind.com/sw/

Would these pads work, as a replacement to tennis balls, to absorb vibrations from travelling to the floor? I can't tell if they are "soft" enough and if they are more suited for industrial applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this from the perspective of having a rigid coupling between the seat, the drummer and the entire kit. Consequently, I think you would need a  "floating" floor setup that can be isolated from the building using some sort of spring/dampening structure. I have not seen the 'tennis-ball' platform other than in this video

which does a good job of concealing the tennis balls from the eye. To be honest, in terms of cost-effectiveness, this looks like a pretty good approach to me.

I fear that the waffle pads - being more suited to building isolation - may be too rigid to be of much use in your application. I personally would go with the tennis-balls if it was me.